# Inserting an object from REST API to Kafka using Kafka Connect API

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have some issues developing a Kafka source connector using Kafka Connect API.

I get data from a REST API using Retrofit and GSON and then try to insert it into the Kafka.

Here is my source task class:

```
public class BitfinexSourceTask extends SourceTask implements BitfinexTickerGetter.OnTickerReadyListener {
private static final String DATETIME_FIELD = "datetime";

private BitfinexService service;
private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
private BlockingQueue<SourceRecord> queue = null;
private BitfinexTickerGetter tickerGetter;

private final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            tickerGetter.get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
private ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture;

@Override
public String version() {
    return VersionUtil.getVersion();
}

@Override
public void start(Map<String, String> map) {
    service = BitfinexServiceFactory.create();
    queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    tickerGetter = new BitfinexTickerGetter(service, this);
    scheduledFuture = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}

@Override
public List<SourceRecord> poll() throws InterruptedException {
    List<SourceRecord> result = new LinkedList<>();
    if (queue.isEmpty()) result.add(queue.take());
    queue.drainTo(result);
    return result;
}

@Override
public void stop() {
    scheduledFuture.cancel(true);
    scheduler.shutdown();
}

@Override
public void onTickerReady(Ticker ticker) {
    Map<String, ?> srcOffset = Collections.singletonMap(DATETIME_FIELD, ticker.getDatetime());
    Map<String, ?> srcPartition = Collections.singletonMap("from", "bitfinex");

    SourceRecord record = new SourceRecord(srcPartition, srcOffset, ticker.getSymbol(), Schema.STRING_SCHEMA, ticker.getDatetime(), Ticker.SCHEMA, ticker);

    queue.offer(record);
}
```

}

I actually was able to build and add the connector. It runs without any errors or something, but the topic was not created. I have decided to create the topic manually and then re-run the connector, but the topic remained empty. `Ticker` is my POJO object containing string and double fields.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: How do you know it runs without errors? Can you add debug statements in your code and look for them in the logs?

Comment: @cricket_007, I use Lenses as UI and adding the connector through it. When I have added it for the first time I had some errors, which were shown there in a separate tab, containing Java exception and stuff. After I have fixed the issue the error tab was empty.